Hide objects behind invisible wall
I am developing a VR application in Unity where I have a 3D object (a plane) flying over the player's head. I am using a Skybox for the background and I want to make the plane "disappear" behind a building. I placed a cube over the building and I want to make it transparent (such that I still see the skybox behind it) but make the plane disappear as you can see in this picture.

It seems to work "fine" as long as I don't move the camera, but as soon as I move it, some artefacts appear (see the picture below)

I am using a shader I found online:
{
    Properties
    {
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType" = "Opaque" "Queue"="Geometry-1" }
        LOD 100

        ZWrite On
        ZTest Always

        Blend Zero One

        Pass
        {

        }
    }
}

Can anyone give me some advice or guide me towards a tutorial on how to properly set up this shader?
Note that I am a real beginner in all this and have almost no idea how shaders work.

What shader/material are you using to draw the buildings? It looks like it's doing some kind pf depth-based distortion, because that code you showed writes solely to the depth buffer.

The buildings are just part of the skybox (a 360 degree image transformed into a skybox), that is why I am trying to add the invisible cube, such that the plane object disappears smoothly behind the fake building

I understand that, but I'm trying to figure out what skybox shader leads to the distortion we're seeing. Can you walk us through the complete steps to create a scene that demonstrates this problem, starting from a new, empty project?

For the skybox part, I just take a 360 picture (generated from a software that downloads a 360 image from Google street view), change the texture shape to cube, then applying it to a material that I defined as skybox -> cubemap. I add a cube in the scene, that I position such that it would hide the building that is present in the skybox (from the POV of the XR rig) to which I applied the shader shown above. I am trying to make that cube invisible to the camera, but still hide the other game objects (the plane), such that it looks like the plane goes behind the building.
